# NodeJS - MariaSQL Row Streaming

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with nodejs and mariasql.

I have a database table for a lot of links (like 4000)

Im using maraisql row streaming but i have some problems.

When i getting row in row stream, i want execute a function, but row stream is getting next row before the function ends. I'm using nightmarejs for visit links. So Row streaming execute a lot of nightmarejs object (electron browser).

So, server is filling and server has be ram overflow..

what can i do ?

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see the context of what you are doing/trying to achieve.  It may be that you need to pause the stream whilst handling the browser.